# How to implement seaborn lmplot to get a gridded plot containing each dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataset. Help to display graphs like `sns.lmplot` conveniently in the form of a 2 x 3 plot figure using seaborn or matplotlib. I try, but they are displayed in one column. And so and so I try, but it does not work. all tables contain the correlation of variables from "SalePrice"

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(4, len(qualitative)/4,figsize=(4*len(qualitative), 4))
sns.lmplot(trainInt, y_vars = ["SalePrice"], x_vars = ('MSSubClass', 'LotFrontage', 'LotArea', 
'OverallQual', 'OverallCond', 'YearBuilt'))
```

there is such a pandas table with data

`trainInt`    -   this is a pandas table

> 

MSSubClass   LotFrontage   OverallQual   OverallCond   YearBuilt    SalePrice

---

10       23      6      43     8     12

12       20      2      46     8     19

11       31      3      13     8     24

> 

you should get six graphs of dependencies `sns.lmplot` in two lines and three columns:

SalePrice  \|\____        SalePrice      I------        SalePrice
   I------I

MSSubClass             LotFrontage             OverallQual

### .

.

SalePrice  \|\**I**        SalePrice      I---\---        SalePrice
   I--I----|

OverallCond           YearBuilt                SalePrice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In order to plot the data, the dataframe must be converted from a wide to long (tidy) format using [`pandas.DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)

  - `SalePrice` must remain a column, to plot against itself, and be in the index, which can be done with [`.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and specifying `drop=False`
- Plot with [`seaborn.lmplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html) using the `col` and `col_wrap` parameters to get a 2 x 3 plot grid.

  - The plot is shown with the default of `ci=95` (confidence interval for the regression estimate).

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'MSSubClass': [10, 12, 11],
        'LotFrontage': [23, 20, 31],
        'OverallQual': [6, 2, 3],
        'OverallCond': [43, 46, 13],
        'YearBuilt': [8, 8, 8],
        'SalePrice': [12, 19, 24]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# display(df)
   MSSubClass  LotFrontage  OverallQual  OverallCond  YearBuilt  SalePrice
0          10           23            6           43          8         12
1          12           20            2           46          8         19
2          11           31            3           13          8         24

# set SalePrice as the index
df.set_index('SalePrice', inplace=True, drop=False)

# convert the dataframe to a long (tidy) form
dfl = df.stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1': 'cats', 0: 'vals'})

# display(dfl)
    SalePrice         cats  vals
0          12   MSSubClass    10
1          12  LotFrontage    23
2          12  OverallQual     6
3          12  OverallCond    43
4          12    YearBuilt     8
5          12    SalePrice    12
6          19   MSSubClass    12
7          19  LotFrontage    20
8          19  OverallQual     2
9          19  OverallCond    46
10         19    YearBuilt     8
11         19    SalePrice    19
12         24   MSSubClass    11
13         24  LotFrontage    31
14         24  OverallQual     3
15         24  OverallCond    13
16         24    YearBuilt     8
17         24    SalePrice    24

# plot the data
sns.lmplot(x='vals', y='SalePrice', col='cats', col_wrap=3, data=dfl, height=4)
plt.xlim(0, 50)
plt.xticks(range(0, 55, 5))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

decided so. the type of chart just came up))

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(round(len(qualitative)/5), 5, figsize=(40, 100))
for var, subplot in zip(qualitative, ax.flatten()):
    sns.set(font_scale = 1.5) 
    sns.regplot(x = var, y = 'SalePrice', data = trainAnaliticQ, ax = subplot);
```

[image]

Comment: This difference between regplot and lmplot is that lmplot combines regplot and FacetGrid so you don't need to create subplots. So they're basically the same thing. Have a nice day.